# in Angular ：how to get "selected" option by ng-selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am learning the Angular yesterday and make a simple demo .

this is my select group :

```
<select class="form-control" size="5">
       <option ng-repeat="m in duringList" ng-bind="m" ng-selected="user.m"></option>
</select>
```

this is save button :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" ng-click="save()">Save</button>
```

in the controller :

```
$scope.save =function () {

    console.log($scope.user.m);
}
```

i try it but it is undefined .

i just expected when i select a option and click the save button , i can get the value in the option without the using Jquery . so please help ~~ thanks a lot .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ng-options` and bind the select to `user.m`.

```
<select ng-model="user.m" ng-options="m for m in duringList"></select>
```

---

If you want to set a default selection, you simply need to set `user.m` to the appropriate value. For example, in your controller

```
$scope.user.m = $scope.user.m || $scope.duringList[0];
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5OMxRkNSOEJpLQ9UIPTu?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Here is also a working [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/UhQ3vEgwfvUXzqrT5QaB?p=preview). I was not sure what your duringList contains so I put in numbers. You can also choose to display something different and put something else in your model if you want, by changing the expression.

Comment: @juunas Given that OP has `ng-bind="m"` in their `<option>`, I assumed they were simply scalar values (numbers or strings). Thanks for the plunk

Comment: yeah , it's working ! , but i also have a little problem , how to config the first one in the duringList as selected option ? just like this : ng-selected="$index" ?

Comment: @qianjiahao I've added an example

Comment: if i want to set a default option before the duringList render , i try this way :  $scope.duringList = duringList;$scope.defaultDuringTime = duringList[0]; in html :ng-selected="defaultFromTime" , but it doesn't work ... no default option ...

Comment: @qianjiahao Seeing as my answer doesn't use any `<option>` tags, I don't see where you could use `ng-selected`.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use `ng-options` and bind a model to the `select`

```js
function ctrl($scope) {
    
    $scope.duringList =  [
        {'v': 1, 't': '1'},
        {'v': 2, 't': '2'},
        {'v': 3, 't': '3'},
        {'v': 4, 't': '4'}
    ];
    
    $scope.save = function(){
        alert($scope.selectedValue);    
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedValue" ng-options="o.v as o.t for o in duringList">
    </select>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" ng-click="save()">Save</button>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or in addition to @Phill you may use:

```
<select ng-model="user.m" class="form-control">
    <option ng-repeat="m in duringList">{{ m }}</option>
</select>
```

and then in a controller:

```
$scope.save =function () {
    console.log($scope.user.m);
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `ng-model="user.m"`

Comment: it depends of console.log(), but you are right it's more close to question.